# Format words under each other

Tags: bash

So, I started learning bash last week and I have to do a task where I should print the content of this `file.txt`:

```
1|george|01/02/2042
2|TPS Reports|03/01/2015
3|Go clubbing this weekend|
4|Metting with family|03/08/2015
5|Help Rose with dating boys|
6|Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange|09/30/2015
```

I have written this code:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do

IFS='|' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
     echo -e "${ADDR[0]}: ${ADDR[1]} \t\t\t ${ADDR[2]}"
done < "$HOME_DIRECTORY_FILE"
```

So, basically this code, will go line by line, take each line, and split it into the array using the delimiter |, then print each part of the array on screen, output:

```
 1: george           01/02/2042
 2: TPS Reports              03/01/2015
 3: Go clubbing this weekend             
 4: Metting with family              03/08/2015
 5: Help Rose with dating boys           
 6: Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange            09/30/2015
```

You might think this is correct, but my instructor said the dates need to be under each other, like this:

```
1: george                                                        01/02/2042
2: TPS Reports                                                   03/01/2015
3: Go clubbing this weekend              
4: Metting with family                                           03/08/2015
5: Help Rose with dating boys            
6: Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange             09/30/2015
```

Is that achievable in bash? Or I should let go of this? My instructor gave the exact output example, spaced this way and said "the output should be neatly formatted (spacing)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `column` command.  It does exactly what you're looking for.

For example:

```
$ cat input.txt
1|george|01/02/2042
2|TPS Reports|03/01/2015
3|Go clubbing this weekend|
4|Metting with family|03/08/2015
5|Help Rose with dating boys|
6|Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange|09/30/2015


$ column --separator \| --table input.txt
1  george                                             01/02/2042
2  TPS Reports                                        03/01/2015
3  Go clubbing this weekend
4  Metting with family                                03/08/2015
5  Help Rose with dating boys
6  Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange  09/30/2015
```

You'll need to do a little pre-formatting to get your numbers to have `:`, but that should be the easy part (you can pipe the modified file into `column`).

Comment: Good answer. You don't need to escape the pipe within single quotes, and you don't need to redirect from the file

Comment: @glennjackman - Good points, fixed.  I also swapped `-t` for `--table` to be consistent.

Comment: It gave me this: **column: illegal option -- -
usage: column [-tx] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]**

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub - Looks like you might be using a different version of `column` that doesn't like the long options.  Just substitute `--separator` with `-s` and `--table` with `-t`.

Comment: Though, for the sixth one it is giving this error **column: line too long** and not printing it.

Comment: @george, how long is that line?

Comment: It is this one "6|Update hacking software for hacking StackExchange|09/30/2015".

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `printf`, although it requires you to guess at the width of the middle column (which `column` computes for you).

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    IFS='|' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
    printf "%d: %-30s %s\n" "${ADDR[0]}" "${ADDR[1]}" "${ADDR[2]}"
done < "$HOME_DIRECTORY_FILE"
```